# Confusion about a proof: Why is checking for discreteness of closed points is enough to prove that it is artinian

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, proof-explanation

I am trying to understand the proof of following theorem, the case 3) implies 1)

[image]

Below is the proof of 3 implies 1 in the above theorem.

[image]

I have two confusions about the proof
Here we are considering a map $f$ from $X=Spec(B)$ to $Spec(k)$. It says since X is quasi-compact, it suffices to show that it' s closed points are discrete.
I don't understand why this is true.

At the end it claims that for each point $p$, we have an isomorphism $k \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X,p}$. Again, I don't understand how they are getting this isomorphism?

Answer (score 1):

$X$ quasi-compact implies that every open cover of $X$ has a finite subcover. Suppose I show that all of it's points are discrete. Take an open cover of $X$ by affines, and note that the only discrete spaces that are closed in an affine space are finite collections of points. Since there exists a finite subcover of this cover of $X$ by open affines, we now know that there are finitely many points in $X$.

The isomorphism $k\to \mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ comes exactly from the statement that $X$ is discrete and the fact that $k$ is algebraically closed: $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ is a zero-dimensional local ring with residue field an algebraic extension of $k$, which means it must be equal to it's residue field, which is $k$ as there are no nontrivial algebraic extensions of an algebraically closed field.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! To prove that $X$ it is enough to prove the discreteness for only closed points in X? I'm still not sure why it is just the closed points? Don't we have to prove that for every point in X?

Comment: Closed points suffice because dimension can be checked at closed points. Since open subschemes in quasicompacts are again quasicompact and quasicompact schemes contain closed points, we know that the dimension of any open affine in $X$ is zero, which implies that the ring of global sections is of krull dimension zero, which implies that the ring of global sections is Artinian.